# How to organize a Vuex vizualizing data project architecture when repeating the component twice?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, architecture, vuex, computed-properties

I’d like to know how to build the Vuejs project architecture.

At the start I’m fetching some object array in the template, passing it to the component as a computed getter.

Next, I’m filtering the initial array, creating a second array ( doing it by sending different filtering client’s query to the mutation -> filling the second array getter). Then creating a second component with computed newly getter array. I’m creating a second getter to get the filtered data as you see for I need to loop in with v-for directive.

So the question is whether the architecture logic is build adequately? Or maybe it's not sufficient creating a second component with relatively second getter. Because it's a kind of goes contra DRY practic ?

```js
// Initaial Component
<template>
  <div v-for"item in initialItems">
    ...
    
  </div>
<template>

computed: {
  items: $store.state.initialItems
}

// Second Component
<template>
  <div v-for"item in filteredItems">
    ...
  </div>
<template>

computed: {
  items: $store.state.filteredItems
}

// Store

state{
  initialItems: [],
  filteredItems: []
}
getters: {
  initialItems() {
    filling state.initialItems
  },
  filterredItems() {
    filling state.filterredItems
  }
}
```

Comment: If we talk only about good behaviour. You need to turn this in a component and passing the data in props. From my pov, i see you do exactly the same things on different data, so you have a duplication.

Comment: Correct me if I’m wrong please, but isn’t props tech unrelevant  with Vuex ?

Comment: Depends on what you want. In some project most of the time, it's props, and on other it's directly from vueX, why?
Because it's subjective to the person who run the project. Inside a component you can like to have no data GET, it's easier to adapt to another, everything come from PROPS and the data is only manage and display. Like in your case, you do exactly the same things on two different data, so it's better to have your manage & display inside a componenent and passing the data by props.
With that you have no conditional display and a easily understandable code :)